# Pages not getting cached in browser

Tags: tomcat, browser-cache, tomcat8, http-caching

I am using apache tomcat server and have a web application rendering several js,css and image files. I want to make sure that these files are cached by the browser so that they are not requested each time. However, I noticed that some files are getting cached while others are not. I found out that the response header from the app has Expires : "Dec 31 1969 at 7:00 PM". After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829553/tomcat-security-constraint-impact-cache) I removed the tomcat security-constraint from the web.xml which removed the header successfully. I also configured the Expires header in my app to 1 week from present. That too didn't make sure that the pages are cached.

Following this I configured the Cache-Control header to public with max-age set to 1 week. None of these changes are helping me. Moreover, the pages getting cached and not getting cached have the same headers as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
ETag: 240983
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Sep 2016 18:49:42 GMT
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 07:34:25 GMT
via: HTTP/1.1 ab-d-klt-tom1
Expires: Wed, 08 Feb 2017 07:35:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Server: Apache
```

Apart from this I have also tried the ExpiresFilter as described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/ExpiresFilter.html) without any luck.

EDIT : My application when deployed in a windows environment with Tomcat and no SSL is successfully caching all the files in the browser.

However, when the app is deployed in a Linux environment with Tomcat and SSL is not caching files. Is SSL causing this?

Comment: Can you show us HTTP headers of a request of a resource that isn't cached by a browser?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev I have edited my post above. Could SSL be causing this issue?

Comment: The request headers are as follows:
GET /html/en/default/***.css HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.62.137.70
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Referer: ***
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.794081272.1485321205; _gat=1; JSESSIONID=***

Comment: Does Chrome display any errors regarding your SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes the "https" and padlock have a cross in chrome and says "Your connection to this site is not secure".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get rid of SSL certificate error. Chrome does not cache resources with such errors.

For more information check Chromium issues below:

- [110649 Browser not caching files if HTTPS is used even if it's allowed by webserver via response headers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110649)
- [103875 Need to test that caching is disabled with certificate errors](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103875)

Comment: thanks for your answer :)  I tested my app on another server with valid SSL certificate and it worked.

Comment: I don't have SSL cert errors, my server certs are just fine, but content isn't cached.